# Is it possible to extract data from dynamic graph with beautiful soup?

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using Beautifulsoup and Python to trying and extract hourly pricing from the chart located on the site below based on date and time variables that will be entered in.

The graph is located on this site: https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/

The way the graph works, is as you move the mouse along the price line, it changes the the date, time and price within a given date range that is set in the top right. When I view the source code, I was able to tell where these details are stored, but the details change as the the mouse is moved across the chart.

My questions is whether or not it's possible to pass a date and time variable and return the price from this chart, or does the fact that it changes the values dynamically in the source code make this impossible?

An example of what I mean:
I would have the following variables
`Date: 2017-12-15
Time: 04:49:51`
And I would use these to search the graph for the corresponding price.

Below is a picture of the portion of code that changes as the mouse moves along the graph:

[image]

I think I can mange to figure out how to programmatically change the date range for the graph, but I don't know how you would manage to grab a specific time, as there is no way to pass that along without moving the mouse across the graph. Andy Ideas?

Comment: `I think I can mange to figure out how to programmatically change the date range`, I don't think that's possible with `requests+bs4`. You should have a look at [Selenium](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use `BeautifulSoup` or `selenium` here, you can get the graph data directly from the api (found by inspecting the network traffic).

```
import requests

api_url = 'https://graphs2.coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/'
r = requests.get(api_url)
json_data = r.json()
```

This will get the main graph, from 2013 to now, with one item per day. If you want to get smaller parts that have more items per day, you'll have to specify a start date and an end date.

The below example will get the prices of the current month only, with 96 items per day.

```
import requests
from datetime import datetime

dt1 = int(datetime(2018, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0).timestamp() * 1000)
dt2 = int(datetime(2018, 1, 21, 0, 0, 0).timestamp() * 1000)
api_url = 'https://graphs2.coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/{}/{}/'
r = requests.get(api_url.format(dt1, dt2))
json_data = r.json()
```

`json_data` is a dictionary that holds all the data in four keys: `'market_cap_by_available_supply'`, `'price_btc'`, `'price_usd'` and `'volume_usd'`. Each of those keys maps to a list of 1714 items. Each of those items is a list of two items, a timestamp and the actual value.

So now we can create a new dictionary with dates as keys and a dict of prices as values.

```
from datetime import datetime

data = {}
for k,v in json_data.items():
    for i in v:
        t = str(datetime.fromtimestamp(i[0]/1000.0))
        if data.get(t):
            data[t][k] = '{:,}'.format(i[1])
        else:
            data[t] = {k: '{:,}'.format(i[1])}
```

And you can access the prices by date, example,

```
print(data.get('2018-01-01 05:59:20'))

{'market_cap_by_available_supply': '231,350,986,890', 'price_btc': '1.0', 'price_usd': '13,791.6', 'volume_usd': '11,137,400,000'}
```

Or you can select a specific item, eg usd price.

```
print(data.get('2018-01-01 05:59:20', {}).get('price_usd'))

13,791.6
```

Comment: Hmmm, in both instances of trying to price by date or by a specific item, I get a return of `None`.

Comment: You'll have to make sure that the date key exists. You can get all the keys with `for k in data: print(k)` Note that the dictionary contains one item per day (2 items for the current day), so perhaps it would be better to access items by date, and ignore the time.

Comment: Also, the data changes when you select smaller periods. Updated the code to grab smaller slices, with more details.

Comment: I know you have already answered this question, but is there some sort of internal timezone at play here? Working through your example I noticed that you get 13,791.60 which when moving your curser through the graph on the website is actually the price for 3:59:20 UTC(Graph time zone) where as when I search the same thing, I get 13,826.50, which is 10:59:20 UTC on the graph. I'm in EST which is 5 hours behind UTC. Could you clear this up for me?